# let insert(L,n) insert natural number n into a singly linked list L. could anyone help me provide a pseudocode description

Tags: algorithm, list, pseudocode

Doing my CS homework, but have no idea how to write the pseudocode.

Let insert(L,n)insert blablabla

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to implement a recursive solution. The code in c++ as following.

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    Node *next;
    Node(int t): val(t), next(nullltr) 
};
//return the node after inserting n.
Node* insert(Node *L, int n) {
   if (L == nullptr) return new Node(n);
   if (L->val < n) {
       L->next = insert(L->next, n);
   } else if (L->val > n) {
       Node *tmp = new Node(n); 
       tmp->next = L;
       L = tmp;
   }
   //do nothing when L->val == n.
   return L;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If no duplicates are allowed you can assume the list is looking something like this

```
...5,6,7,8...
```

Using that knowledge, you know you need to step a maximum of n steps to reach the destination. You can do this via recursion or looping through.

Recursion(Node e,int n):

1. If e.value is n return.
2. If e.next is not NULL, call Recursion(e.next, n) else e.next = new node consisting of n.
3. Finish.

Iterative-way(int n):

1. node = list.root
2. Loop while node is not null:
3. If node.value is n, stop.
4. End loop
5. If node.next is NULL, node.next = new node consisting of n. else (new node consisting of n).next = node.next and node.next = new node consisting of n.